# Expo app crashes with react-native-google-mobile-ads [ios_appd_id key not found in react-native-google-mobile-ads key in app.json]

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, admob, eas

I am experiencing this error with react-native-google-mobile-ads: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/issues/194

My app is using an expo managed workflow with the EAS build system.

My app builds for android but fails on iOS with the following error: `ios_appd_id key not found in react-native-google-mobile-ads key in app.json. App will crash without it.` Which is strange because by app.json has the correct definition:

```
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxx",
    "user_tracking_usage_description": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
  }
```

Regardless of how I altered my code or dependencies, this kept showing up. In an attempt to debug and find a reproducible sample I slowly built a fresh project which was created via expo init (as was my initial project). However, I am now at the point where I have literally copied every file exactly into the new, fresh app including all assets (icons, splashes) and I can not reproduce the bug at all. The two apps are exact replicas of one another (code, app.json, eas.json, package.json) In fact, the new fresh app works perfectly fine and behaves as expected in both development and production mode. I am royally confused. The error above occurs in the "run fastlane" phase of the build process.

The fastlane log with the error is here: https://pastebin.com/4cD8T3Sn
The log from the fresh app is the exact same except that the final lines of the log are success messages instead:

```
› Copying   ios/googleadmobtest/Supporting/Expo.plist ➜ ./Expo.plist
› Compiling googleadmobtest » SplashScreen.storyboard
› Preparing googleadmobtest » Info.plist
› Executing googleadmobtest » Bundle React Native code and images
› Generating debug googleadmobtest » googleadmobtest.app.dSYM
› Executing googleadmobtest » [CP] Copy Pods Resources
› Executing googleadmobtest » [CP-User] [RNGoogleMobileAds] Configuration
› Signing   googleadmobtest » googleadmobtest.app
› Creating  googleadmobtest » googleadmobtest.app
› Archive Succeeded
Generated plist file with the following values:
▸ -----------------------------------------
▸ {
▸   "method": "ad-hoc",
▸   "provisioningProfiles": {
▸     "com.arham23.googleadmobtest": "c88fe3cb-0ed2-427d-ae68-ec6a484dccca"
▸   },
▸   "signingStyle": "manual"
▸ }
▸ -----------------------------------------
$ /usr/bin/xcrun /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.205.2/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist '/var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/gym_config20220815-4163-q9vcsf.plist' -archivePath /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-08-15/googleadmobtest\ 2022-08-15\ 23.44.51.xcarchive -exportPath '/var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/gym_output20220815-4163-1ishkbk' OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain /var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/turtle-v2-9ac5a45d-33ef-4193-bf51-33b05b2e1e98.keychain"
Compressing 1 dSYM(s)
$ cd '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-08-15/googleadmobtest 2022-08-15 23.44.51.xcarchive/dSYMs' && zip -r '/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/build/googleadmobtest.app.dSYM.zip' *.dSYM
▸   adding: googleadmobtest.app.dSYM/ (stored 0%)
▸   adding: googleadmobtest.app.dSYM/Contents/ (stored 0%)
▸   adding: googleadmobtest.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/ (stored 0%)
▸   adding: googleadmobtest.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/ (stored 0%)
▸   adding: googleadmobtest.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/googleadmobtest (deflated 75%)
▸   adding: googleadmobtest.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist (deflated 44%)
Successfully exported and compressed dSYM file
Successfully exported and signed the ipa file:
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/build/googleadmobtest.ipa
```

I can provide any other information necessary, I'm somewhat new to expo and react native so I wasn't sure what would be relevant. It seems like something is wrong with my original app's configuration but I have no idea what the issue could be. I'd like to try deleting all the ios pods and reinstalling but the app is managed by expo and I'm unsure how to accomplish this in the expo CLI. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If so, what did you do? Thanks!

Comment: @teewuane I think the github issue has some more activity now, this issue might be caused by some special character issues when react-native-google-mobile-ads parses the app.json. The only way I was able to resolve was to literally rewrite the app.json by hand. I think I cloned a test repo and then slowly added things back until I realized I had just recreated the whole file - it works now though, but only using that repo.

Comment: I found that my app.json had some bad json in it (an extra comma). Hope this helps someone else. Although I'm still having a heck of a time getting the app to build. I think it's now a bad google admob id or the one I'm using is too old or something.

Answer (score 2):

To get around this error, I split the config into two files. Expo by default loads `app.config.json` over `app.json` and `react-native-google-mobile-ads` reads `app.json`

`app.json`

```
{ 
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
        ...app ids
    }
}
```

`app.config.json`

```
{
    "expo": {
        "name": ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue then I tried to split app.json into 2 parts like this:
In the app.json, before copying and pasting the following code

```
{
 "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
 }
}
```

from the https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads#configure-outbound-requests
I moved
 `"name": "...", "displayName": "...",`
to a new file named **app.config.json** is the same directory as app.json.
**Conclusion:**
**app.json**

```
{
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

**app.config.json**

```
{
 "name": "...",
  "displayName": "...",
}
```

Note that: because you changed the app.json -> app.config.json so wherever you implement data from **app.json** you need to change to **app.config,json**
For example in my index.js has a line **import {name as appName} from './app.json'** change it in to **import {name as appName} from './app.config.json'**
Wish you guys will solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: When i try this above answer (which seems to be fairly widely accepted) i am given the error:

 - Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist" - 

Does anyone else get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessary anymore. You can have both in the same app.json file.

**app.json**

```
"expo": {
    "name": "example",
    "slug": "example-slug",
    ...
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
```

In android is necessary to update your AndroidManifest.xml generated after `npx expo prebuild` with:

```
<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-2251305723458145~xxxxxxxxxx"/>
    ...
</application>
```

In **ios** you need to configure you info.plist file: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist

To test just run `npx expo run:android/ios`

I hope I've helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the app id to the specific config inside ios/config and android/config inside your app.json
Check this out: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#googlemobileadsappid

The link above is for iOS, which is similar to Android. They are in ios/config and android/config in your app.json - These settings will tell Expo to add the app id to the info.plist (ios) and manifest when running prebuild. You still need to keep the react-native-google-mobile-ads in your current config. So, there're 2 places in app.json need to be setup:

- googleMobileAdsAppId inside the platform config key.
- The config that outside the expo key

Note that you cannot add using the infoplist key inside iOS since expo will ignore it, you have to you the specific config in the document I provided